# C# file size limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, size, c#-2.0

I have a website built with ASP.NET (.NET 2.0). I have a lot of classes in my business logic, and I keep all of them in one file (BL.cs).

I now got to a stage where I have 11,000 lines of code in this file. Is this a problem - should I separate it into several files, each class in a different file? Is there a limit that the cs file shouldn't exceed?

Comment: There is no limit on CS file size except other than OS restrictions, but there are best practices that you should follow and none of them states to put all your business logic in one file.

Comment: a class per file is preferable

Answer (score 8):

I stick to the following rule: 1 file per class (unless for nested classes of course). 11,000 lines of code in a single file looks monstrous.

Answer (score 6):

To be honest I don't know if there is a size limit, but 11.000 lines of code is a lot to handle in a single file.

You will find that VS runs a lot smoother if you split the code into multiple files and it will make it easier for you and your fellow developers to focus on a specific set of classes for any given task.

Programming is all about building complex systems from simple parts. Storing all your parts in a single, giant file goes against that idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep each class in separate file for better readability and managability.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a limit on the file size, I've seen EF files at 30k+ lines, **however**, you *should* be separating everything into individual files anyway for just plain usability and readability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a problem from a maintability point of view.

You will almost never need hand written code to be more than a few hundred lines per class and you should always aim to use one class per file ( and name files with the same name as your class ). This is general good form for managing a project, especially a large one.

If this is one huge auto-generated class you might consider splitting it into multiple files using the **partial** keyword in each.